# Assigning values to numpy cells in one go

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array of zeros. I want to assign 1 to multiple cells. How do I do this?

So for example:

```
arr = np.zeros((5,3)) 
idx = [0,1,2,2,0]
```

Here, `idx` is the column indices of the cells I want changed.

So my desired output is:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try advanced indexing:

```
arr[np.arange(len(arr)), idx] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
current = 0

for row in arr:
    col = idx[current]
    row[col] = 1
    current += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
arr = np.zeros((5,3))
idx = [0,1,2,2,0]
#Validate idx elements here 
#Distribute 1s to columns randomly
for x in idx:
    while True:
        i = randint(0,arr.shape[0] - 1)
        if arr[i][x] == 1:
            continue #Try again 
        else:
            arr[i][x] = 1
            break
print (arr)
```